# Написание адреса

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятые при указании географического положения объекта? Например:

"... в поселке Поленово, Заокского района, Тульской области".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые в этом случае не нужны. Например, при заполнении анкеты надо писать: родился в поселке Поленово Заокского района Тульской области.

Нет оснований для постановки запятых, так как это не однородные члены, а сложное словосочетание со связью управление Р.п.

http://admhmansy.ru/upload/iblock/a5a/порядок%20заполнения%20анкеты.doc

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

К уточняющим членам предложения(определениям  или обстоятельствам — смотря по
контексту)относятся названия районов, областей и т.п., обозначающие местонахождение поселков, деревень и т.п, а также указания в адресах: В деревне Уваровке, ***Петровского района, Калужской области***, состоялся праздник уражая; Поселок Новые Горки, ***Щелковского района, Московской области,*** находится недалеко от станции Болшево; Москва, улица Плющиха, д. 38, кв. 2.Но в вашем случае, запятые не нужны.