# д. Малиновка(,) Логойского района

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

(д. Малиновка(,) Логойского района) (*текст должен быть в скобках)

- д. Малиновка, Логойский район – здесь запятая не вызывает сомнений. А в данном случае нужна запятая?

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34885/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: И еще: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424806/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **д. Малиновка Логойского района.**

Образец: Деревня Леньково сельского поселения Ивановское Рузского района Московской области. https://www.moscowmap.ru/oblast/ruzskiy-raion/lenkovo.html

При такой записи мы имеем **неоднородные несогласованные определения**, выраженные падежной формой (Р.п.).

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишет журнал «[Делопроизводство и документооборот на предприятии](http://www.delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=5441)» (март 2009):

> Если сравнить два варианта написания адреса, представленные в Примере 9, то вы увидите, что в первом случае район и область указаны через запятую в именительном падеже, а во втором – без запятой со склонением. Оба варианта допустимы.

Пример 9

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]